# Edit email address in Google Form

Tags: email, google-forms

Here's the steps I took:

- Made a quiz in Google Forms.
- Enabled email address collection.
- Sent out the quiz to twenty-five email addresses.
- Stopped accepting responses.
- Released the scores.

However, on the last step, I was surprised to receive two "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)" messages with a DNS error (responded with code NXDOMAIN, domain name not found). While the local-part is correct, two of the the domain names were recorded incorrectly. One has two letters transposed and another has an `i` replaced with a `t`.

How can I fix the domain of the recorded email addresses?

Comment: do you wnat to change Email Address to which Google Forms Responses are Sent ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.